# Does a matrix have block diagonal structure if and only if its matrix exponential has it as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, matrix-exponential

Obviously, if

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{C} & \mathbf{0}\\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{D}\end{bmatrix}$$

then

$$e^{A}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{e^C} & \mathbf{0}\\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{e^D}\end{bmatrix}$$

Given any invertible matrix $X$ we can express it as $X = e^A$  (but complex matrix $A$ is not unique until $X$ is not from one-parameter subgroup of $\mbox{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$). Anyway, given that $X$ has a block diagonal structure then does $A$ need to have block diagonal structure as well?

Comment: Perhaps you could try showing something like this : can any invertible matrix can be expressed as the logarithm of some other matrix? I don't think you'll have uniqueness either but maybe it's one way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. A counterexample is
$\mathbf A=\pmatrix{0&2\pi\mathrm i\\2\pi\mathrm i&0}$, with $\mathrm e^{\mathbf A}=I$.